# How to get java class from object in kotlin?

Tags: unit-testing, kotlin, mockito, kotlin-reflect

I am trying `mockito` to mock a `getValue` function that consumes a java class as parameter.

To simplify, i did the following test:

```
@Test
fun test1() {
    val map = HashMap<String,Any>()
    val v:Long = 1L 
    map["K"]= v

    println(map["K"]!!::class.java) //prints class java.lang.Long
    println(Long::class.java) //prints long

    val dss = Mockito.mock(DataSnapshot::class.java)

    Mockito.`when`(dss.getValue( map["K"]!!::java.class))
            .thenReturn( map["K"]!!)

    //production code uses calls the function like this but it fails to get the value. Returns null;
    Assert.assertEquals( map["K"],dss.getValue(Long::class.java))
}
```

As the prints show, the type in `map["K"]!!::class.java` is different from `Long::class.java`.

If i mock the method using the type inline it works:

```
Mockito.`when`(dss.getValue( Long::class.java))
            .thenReturn( map["K"]!!)
```

How can i mock the method in a way that the type parameter hasn't to be determined by a long switch logic?

Some insides in kotlin and java types could help.

Answer (score 2):

If you're asserting against `java.lang.Long`, use `Long?::class.java`. `Long::class.java` will give you the primitive `long` on the JVM. Nullable `Long` instead maps to the boxed version - `java.long.Long`.

Comment: Can't use that solution because method i am trying to mock, `dss.getValue(Class<*> T)`, does not accept a generic nullable .

Comment: You can always just go with `java.lang.Long::class.java`